# ':firebase_core:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, gradle

I cannot build the app after the upgrade flutter. Getting the following error "Execution failed for task ':firebase_core:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':firebase_core:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Failed to calculate the value of task ':firebase_core:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' property 'options.generatedSourceOutputDirectory'.
> Querying the mapped value of map(java.io.File property(org.gradle.api.file.Directory, property(org.gradle.api.file.Directory, fixed(class org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFilePropertyFactory$FixedDirectory, C:\Users\ahmed azami\Desktop\social_app\build\firebase_core\generated\ap_generated_sources\debug\out))) org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFilePropertyFactory$ToFileTransformer@a5453a7) before task ':firebase_core:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' has completed is not supported

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5m 47s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1strong text

Answer (score 0):

I think it is due to androidX. Just append these 2 lines at the end of `gradle.properties`
`android.enableJetifier=true`
`android.useAndroidX=true`

Comment: Thanks, I fixed by upgrading the Gradle version.